# Expandable listview not collapsing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, listview

I'm going through this tutorial (https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section) trying to build an expandable listview into my application. The only differance between my code and the tutorials is I'm doing it with a storyboard.

I seem to have it almost fully functional but I have one problem. The rows are collapsing and then are repopulating without being clicked a second time. I've gone through my code multiple times but I can't seem to find the problem.

Here is my code:

List View Controller Class:

```
import UIKit

class ItemListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var sections = [Item]()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sections = [
        Item(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro", "iMac", "Mac Pro", "Mac mini", "Accessories", "OS X El Capitan"]),
        Item(name: "iPad", items: ["iPad Pro", "iPad Air 2", "iPad mini 4", "Accessories"]),
        Item(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"])
    ]

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "ItemTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ItemTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ItemTableViewCell.")
    }

    cell.itemLabel.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCellIdentifier = "ItemHeaderTableViewCell"
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerCellIdentifier) as! ItemHeaderTableViewCell

    headerCell.itemHeaderLabel.text = sections[section].name
    headerCell.setCollapsed(sections[section].collapsed)

    headerCell.section = section
    headerCell.delegate = self

    return headerCell
}
}

extension ItemListViewController: ItemHeaderTableViewCellDelegate {
    func toggleSection(_ header: ItemHeaderTableViewCell, section: Int) {
        let collapsed = !sections[section].collapsed

        // Toggle collapse
        sections[section].collapsed = collapsed
        header.setCollapsed(collapsed)

        // Adjust the height of the rows inside the section
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0 ..< sections[section].items.count {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Item Header Table View Cell Class:

```
import UIKit

protocol ItemHeaderTableViewCellDelegate {
func toggleSection(_ header: ItemHeaderTableViewCell, section: Int)
}

class ItemHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: ItemHeaderTableViewCellDelegate?
var section: Int = 0

@IBOutlet var itemHeaderLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ItemHeaderTableViewCell.tapHeader(_:))))
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func tapHeader(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as? ItemHeaderTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    delegate?.toggleSection(self, section: cell.section)
}

func setCollapsed(_ collapsed: Bool) {
    // Animate the arrow rotation (see Extensions.swf)
    // arrowLabel.rotate(collapsed ? 0.0 : CGFloat(M_PI_2))
}
}
```

Item Table View Cell:

```
import UIKit

class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var itemLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Item class:

```
import UIKit

class Item {

var name: String!
var items: [String]!
var collapsed: Bool!

init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false) {
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.collapsed = collapsed
}
}
```

So why are my cells repopulating when I try to collapse them? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the function that actually shows/hides the rows:

```
// from the GitHub repo you linked to:
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].collapsed! ? 0 : 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard, I have a repository for Expandable UITableView you can check it out, if it works for you.

https://github.com/PriyamDutta/PDExpandable